# React state update issue | multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have 2 tabs Articles and add articles.
On Articles tab all articles are shown in a list.
I can add articles from articles page.

What I want is when a new articled is added it should auto-refresh the articles page without navigating to articles tab from add-articles page.

In order to test this, I have opened articles page on one tab and add-articles page on other tab or in other browser.

I am also using context API.

is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, it's a little vague what you're asking here. Also, could you clarify whether you're talking about 2 tabs on the same page or 2 separate pages. You said tabs at first and then started referring to them as pages.

Comment: Hi, Thank for replying quickly and sorry for not explaining  question well. I have 2 urls /articles and /add_article. I have opened both urls in browser with 2 tabs, one for articles and other tab for add-articles.
I want to know that if I add an article on one browser tab, is it possible that other browser tab where I list articles will update automatically without reloading or triggering any event.
In simple words suppose I am on my profile page and you update something on my profile on your PC, I want to see the updated info on my page on my PC without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use two React hooks: `useState()` and `useEffect()`. I'm not sure what you're using to store your articles, so I'll use pseudo-code.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function App() {
    // Initialize articles state to empty array
    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

    // Side effect to fetch articles
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchArticles = () => {
            /**
             * Code to fetch articles from server
             */
            setArticles('result set from fetch');
        }

        const checkForNewArticles = () => {
            /**
             * Ideally, you'd want to have code on the server that 
             * compares your local article count to count in database
             */
            if ('newArticles logic here') fetchArticles();
        }

        fetchArticles();
        const interval = setInterval(checkForNewArticles, 5000);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {
                articles.map((article) => (
                    <div key={article.id}>{article.title}</div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

The above code will call fetchArticles on page load and then call it again very 5 seconds. This is called polling. You could simplify it by fetching all articles on every iteration, but that would use a lot of network bandwidth needlessly.

Comment: Thank you for explaining everything. Just a quick question though, Instead of fetching content every 5 seconds can't I use useCallback hook to refresh the content.
Here is my code attached add.js and app.js
https://jsfiddle.net/Aamirhassan/rnucd49b/10/

I know this is not proper way of showing code but I am new to fiddle.
Please can you have a look at this and suggest anything.
Actually I want to get rid of setInterval. just like ASANA, we add ticket on one browser tab and we can see that ticket appear on other browser tab.

Comment: Ok, I was a little confused. You're talking about the ephemeral state of your app, not stored (persistent) data. So, the state of the app is stored on the client, so if you open what is basically another instance of the app in another browser tab, it's basically like two users running two copies of the same client. You need some way to store the state on the server (see above example) or on the client, perhaps by cookies or localStorage.

Comment: Thank you Desingly for all your efforts. I would go with Redux persistant localstorage.

Comment: A fine option. Good luck!